# XAML Make newly created tab selected by default?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

Within my main window when I create a new table the tab is not selected. Because of this the view does not display until I select my tab.

Here is an image of the newly created tab after I click the view report button. Below is the content template i am using.

[image]

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ReportContentTemplate">
    <TabControl Margin="4" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
                    <Button Content="X" Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}" Cursor="Hand" Height="16" Width="16" Margin="4,0,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Courier" FontSize="9" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Set the selected index to the index of the newly created tab. Show how you add the tab to the control. after adding it. get it's index and then set the index of the tabcontrol to that

Comment: Hint: StackOverflow posts support images. Using that feature saves one click for the people who might help you.